# Trading View - Gap calc - How to tell if the day trading session started vs a state where market is closed?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a script that makes gap calculation, 
I order to calculate gap, I have two situations :
1. During the market is closed I want to use the last extended hours price 
2. When market is open I want to use the open price / yesterday's close

```
is_newbar(res) => 
    change(time(res,session.regular)) != 0

new_day = is_newbar("D") ? 1 : 0
// new_day returns 0 even during the market hours.

o = security(tick, "D", open)
c = security(tick, "D", close)

extended_close = new_day ? o : get_extended_last("5")
session_close = new_day ? c[1] : c

gap = extended_close / session_close
```

My view is 5m chart. and I want the **daily gap**

or is there an easier way to get gap ?

Answer (score 0):

You were testing for regular sessions at "D" resolution, so the condition was never true. I don't understand your requirements about which price to use when, but using these conditions you should be able to get the prices you need. If not, just comment.

```
//@version=4
study("")
regularSession() => 
    time(timeframe.period, session.regular)
regularSessionBegins = regularSession() and not regularSession()[1]

plotchar(regularSessionBegins, "regularSessionBegins", "▲", location.top)
plotchar(regularSession(), "regularSession()", "•", location.bottom)
```

[image]